# A question on Spivak's proof on manifolds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is hard for me to ask since I have to write out the entire long proof done in Spivak's book on Manifolds.

If anyone has the book, it would be great. This question concerns the Inverse Function Theorem done in the book.

Spivak states that

$$|D_jf^i(x) - D_jf^i(a)| < 1/2n^2$$ for all $i,j$ and $x \in U$

Here $U$ is a **closed rectangle** set, $n$ is an integer.

I suspect it has to do something with Lemma 2.10 (the previous page), which states

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. If there is a number M such that $|D_jf^i(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$ in the interior of $A$, then $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq n^2 M|x - y|$$

I probably need to play around with the condition $|D_jf^i(x)| \leq M$

Comment: I personally do not like Spivak's proof. Try reading Rudin's proof from chapter 8 of *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, which is a bit shorter and easier to understand. One difference is that Rudin defines "continuously differentiable" to mean "$Df:A\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is continuous" (giving $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ the operator norm), while Spivak defines it in terms of partial derivatives. The former definition generalizes very well to higher (Fréchet) derivatives, while the partial derivatives approach gets messy.

Comment: (continued) Another difference is that Rudin uses the contraction principle, while Spivak uses the "minimize the function" approach.

Comment: Chapter 9 of Rudin, I think.

Comment: @wj32 However, the later is the standard. See, for example, [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function#Multivariate_differentiability_classes).

Comment: @FrankScience: Only in elementary multivariable calculus or differential geometry texts. Things become much nicer when defining the derivative properly (Fréchet derivative). See Lang.

Comment: @wj32 Spivak's is just of that kind. It's not easy for me to understand Rudin's proof, as well as Spivak's proof. However, based on Rudin's proof, one can simplify the problem by normalization, viz. $a=f(a)=0$ and $f'(0)=\operatorname{id}$. WLOG, suppose that $\lVert f(x)-x\rVert\le\lVert x\rVert/2$ in the (closed) unit ball, then $f$ is onto the (open) half unit ball around $0$.

Comment: @wj32 In addition, inverse function theorem could be refined. See [Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The broader context is this:

> There is a closed rectangle $U$ containing $a$ in its interior such that
>
> $\mathbf{1.}$ $f(x) \neq f(a)$ if $x \in U$ and $x \neq a$.
>
> Since $f$ is continuously differentiable in an open set containing $a$, we can also assume that
>
> $\mathbf{2.}$ $\det f'(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in U$
>
> $\mathbf{3.}$ $|D_jf^i(x) - D_jf^i(a)| < 1/2n^2$ for all $i,j$ and $x \in U$.

The point is that since $f$ is continuously differentiable (in an open set containing $a$), each $D_jf^i$ is a continuous function (in an open set containing $a$).  Since $D_jf^i$ is continuous at $x = a$, (by taking $\epsilon = 1/2n^2)$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$|x - a| < \delta \implies |D_jf^i(x) - D_jf^i(a)| < 1/2n^2.$$
If we choose $U$ small enough so that $U \subset \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon |x-a| < \delta\}$, then we have that $|D_jf^i(x) - D_jf^i(a)| < 1/2n^2$ for all $x \in U$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, $U$ is closed (a picture is right beside the book).  Does this actually change anything? Because your delta neighbourhood is open

Comment: No, it doesn't really change anything.  We can choose a smaller $U$ if necessary.

Comment: I thought continuity is mapping from one open set to another, not a closed set to an open set.

Comment: Continuity can be defined by saying that the _pre_-images of open sets are open, yes. In metric spaces (such as $\mathbb{R}^n$), this is equivalent to the epsilon-delta definition, which is what's used above. The point, however, is that once continuity is used to give us an open ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $a$, we can choose the closed rectangle $U$ to lie inside this open ball.

Comment: At this point in the proof, all Spivak is doing is trying to _choose_ a closed rectangle $U$ with certain properties. One of the properties he wants $U$ to have is that the inequality $|D_jf^i(x) - D_jf^i(a)| < 1/2n^2$ holds for all $x \in U$.  This can be accomplished if every $x \in U$ satisfies $|x-a|< \delta$ -- meaning that $U$ is taken small enough to lie inside the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $a$.

Comment: @sizz: Is all of this clear, or no?